# Can I use the word "grabbable"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, suffixes, is-it-a-word

I intend to describe something possible to be held by hand.

I want to use the word in this fragment:

> Flat 3-dimensions and **grabbable** 2-dimensions.

I'm trying to express in my paper that the dimension seems to be reversed because of the dominance of smartphones. Basically, a plane cannot be held by our hand. But because we have become so familiar with LCD monitors - even more than external reality - I think we understand virtual reality as 'flat 3-dimension' and reality as 'grabbable plane'.

I've found words like 'holdable', 'grippable', 'grabbable' and 'graspable' but I'm not sure which one would be best.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary to examine the meanings of the adjectives you are considering?

Comment: You can (in the 'are not forbidden by some notional _Academie_' sense) use _any_ word. Or even any non-word. You claim that 'grabbable' _is_ a word. But you offer no evidence to support this. You might check (under 'grab') in Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. // I'm not happy with your intended metaphorical usage; it confuses me rather than helps my understanding.

Comment: Are you really after 'concrete'?

Comment: I think that in the context you describe, 'grabbable' works just fine if  you are implying that you can grab hold of a virtual plane and manipulate it, move it out of the way etc.

Comment: I think in context, "flat 3-dimensions and grabbable 2-dimensions" might actually work. But I also think that without any context, no one will understand you, and you will have to provide the additional explanation as you just did. By the way, note that there is no such thing as "3-dimensions". There is "3 dimensions", and there is "3D". And they don't quite mean the same thing. Lastly, the comma before the "and" is wrong. Remove it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that something virtual, untouchable appears to be real, as if you could touch it? [Tangible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tangible) might be a word that fits.

Comment: Thank you for all of you. I tried to find the word in a dictionary but couldn't. And 'tangible' seems to be the word I'm looking for! Thank you very much.@Lucky

Comment: grabbable: "adjective   (informal) able to be grabbed"  Collins English Dictionary (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grabbable)   Found by googling "grabbable"

Comment: while it's probably not canonized by modern standards, it's completely valid english grammatical combination. Whether a word following grammatical rules is deemed legit or not is really rather arbitrary. Language evolves. everything canon today was once not canon in the past. Thumb your nose at the "that's not even a word" type of people. all of them are verbs, and they have the form where -able or -able can be appended to them. why the heck not.

Comment: *"I think we understand virtual reality as 'flat 3-dimension' and reality as 'grabbable plane'."* I don't understand reality as a grabbable plane. I understand reality as a grabbable space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for "handheld".

> **handheld**
>
> : designed to be used while being held in your hands

[Merriam-Webster reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handheld)